# UITableView - Show Reorder Control always but still be able to delete and select rows

Tags: ios, uikit, uitableview

I've got a UITableView and I want to have the following things at the same time:

- Be always able to reorder items (show reorder control always)
- Always being able to delete items by swiping to the side and reveal the delete button
- Do not show that minus sign on the side
- Be always able to select (highlight) a row

I tried a couple of things but couldn't achieve all at the same time.
Which settings steps are needed to achieve all this? Which delegate methods must return which values? Which flags / settings must be set on the cells?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution since this was originally posted?

Comment: I'm always leaving my TableView in editing mode and using SWReavealTableViewCell for being able to delete cells: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealTableViewCell